# ExtJS5 TypeError: Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

I am trying to create a grid with progress bar in an MVVM project. It used to work but when i had refresh my app with

```
sencha app refresh
```

I started to get "TypeError: Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager is not a constructor" error.

This is the panel that i used my grid in it:

```
Ext.define("GeoPortal.view.south.South",{
    "extend": "GeoPortal.geox.components.Panel",
    "controller": "south",
    "viewModel": {
        "type": "south"
    },
    "region": 'south',
    "collapsible": true,
    "collapsed": true,
    "title": "SouthPanel",
    "xtype": "southPanel",
    "items": [{
        xtype: 'gxPagedGrid',
        params: {
            store: 'GeoPortal.store.Companies',
            pageSize: 5,
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Price',
                sortable: true,
                formatter: 'usMoney',
                dataIndex: 'price',
                width: 75
            }, {
                text: 'Change',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'change',
                width: 80
            }, {
                text: '% Change',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'pctChange',
                width: 100
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```

And this is my pagedGrid class:

```
Ext.define('GeoPortal.geox.components.PagedGrid', {
    extend: 'GeoPortal.geox.components.Grid',
    xtype: 'gxPagedGrid',
    using: [
        'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
        'Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager'
    ],

    initComponent: function () {

        var store = new Ext.create(this.params.store, {
            pageSize: this.params.pageSize,
            proxy: {
                enablePaging: true
            }
        });

        Ext.apply(this, {
            using: store,
            store: store,
            columns: this.params.columns,
            bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: this.params.pageSize,
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true
                // FIX: this
                //plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager()
            }
        });
        this.callParent();
    },

    afterRender: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.getStore().load();
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Ext.create('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager')` instead of calling constructor?

Comment: Write that comment as an answer my friend, because it's the right answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably problem occurs because you use `using` instead of `requires` in class definition. That's why `Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager` is not loaded when you try create instance.

`Ext.create('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager')` is working (as mentioned in commen), because it is capable of load class on demand, that's why it is better to use `Ext.create` over `new`.